# Preserve Emojis with Get-Content Powershell

Tags: powershell, csv, rss, feed

I want to preserve Emojis with Get-Content.
When I pull the string from the feed I get the following result:

```
$WebResponse = Invoke-RestMethod $website
$str_outputNAME = $feed.title 
Wanna try?
```

But when I save the content of the file and append it after I have the following result:

```
$content = (Get-Content -Path $file) -join "`n"
$toWrite = $top_line+$toWrite+$content
$toWrite | Out-File -FilePath $file;
Wanna try???
```

Background-Info

I want to use Powershell to read a rss-feed.
Therefor I need to append a string at the start of my CSV-File on update.

Comment: Try specifying the encoding when writing the file(s) `Out-File -FilePath $file -Encoding unicode`. Also, there's an `-Append` option for Out-File which could save you some code.

Comment: Thank YOU, I added `Get-Content -Path $file -Encoding UTF32` at the end and now it seems to preserve the Emojis, but anyway I have a strange last entry consisting of 900 `�` Also when I checked the output csv it told me UTF16LE but seems like powershell only supports 32 and not 16
Anyway huge thankyou!

Comment: Sadly did not work for me. Wich Encoding Type you think exactly of? Btw im working with `5.1.18362.752`

Answer (score 0):

Because my question was regarding `*.csv` files I found that a better way is too use

```
$content = Import-Csv -Path $file
```

instead of

```
$content = Get-Content -Path $file
```

Now all my Emojis are preserved within the file **but** the processing of the script takes twice the time now.

I tried all different possible `Get-Content -Encoding` arguments but without luck.
Always resulted in loss towards the formatting of emojis.